# send bulk sms using gsm modem in java

Tags: java, sms

I wanted to develop application that can send bulk sms. i have no idea how to implement it.  I have app that can send only one sms by reading [this web site](http://www.harshadura.net/2011/10/simply-send-sms-using-java-with-your.html) . but I want to know how i can send bulk sms.please give me idea how can i do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Uhm, why don't you just loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've gotten that module to work, adding a loop around the gsmModem.Sender call should send a specified amount of messages. I would suggest adding in a sleep method, as your modem probably won't be able to handle all of the AT commands at once.